# Liquid: checking if echoed value equals a string

Tags: shopify, liquid

`{{item}}` is an object but when used like this it echoes `VideoDrop` or `PostDrop`

I need to know which one before the liquid proccesses in the dom... Example:

```
    {% if item == "VideoDrop" %}
        {% assign image = image2 %}
    {% else %}
        {% assign image = image1 %}
    {% endif %}
```

but the `if` always returns false... What is the correct way to check the value of `{{item}}` ?

Answer (score 1):

What object type is `item` from (products, articles etc.)?
Maybe you can use this code:

```
{% if item == "VideoDrop" or item == "PostDrop" %}
   {% assign image = image2 %}
{% else %}
   {% assign image = image1 %}
{% endif %}
```

If there are whitespaces on the start/end of the string, you can use this:

```
{% if item contains "VideoDrop" or item contains "PostDrop" %}
```

edit:
If you want to check, if product has assigned collections named VideoDrop or PostDrop, you can use this code:

```
{% for collection in product.collections %}
    {% assign item = collection.title %}
    {% if item == "VideoDrop" or item == "PostDrop" %}
       {% assign image = image2 %}
    {% else %}
       {% assign image = image1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But the code above will result in image2 overwritten by image1 in some cases. It would be better if you could expand your question and show us, what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am new to liquid... I know that it is processed server side so i don't think it will be as straightforward as what we are trying. These options didnt work. `item` comes from `{% for item in collection %}`

Comment: @Omar - collection is not an array of items. So `{% for item in collection %}` will not work. I'm gonna edit my answer and put there an example with checking collection title (name).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call a specific value inside the object to use it in statements.

It could be {{ item.type }} for example.
You need to check object documentation to retrieve value you need inside.

Answer (score 0):

In Shopify, an `xxxDrop` response is a placeholder for "The thing that you're trying to print to the screen can't be printed to the screen directly"

You will need to check for a property on the object to get the behaviour you're after. A great resource is the [Shopify Liquid Reference](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects)  (also linked in the top of the Shopify theme editor in a really easy-to-miss-spot: right after the "Older Versions" link beside the file name).

Checking `item.type` can sometimes help, but Shopify doesn't set `type` for absolutely every kind of object, so before using anything you'll want to test it to make sure you're getting the info you expect.  (`item.type` is mainly set for the types of objects that can be returned in search results... and not much else)

Hope this helps!